# Where a direcrory mounted to Docker container is located by default?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

There is a run command with mounting a folder to a Docker container.

`docker run --volume my_folder:/mnt/mqm  my-image-name`

We see that the bind folder name `my_folder` is passed without its path.
It is definitely not the same as `./my_folder` path, which is relative to the current folder.

I can't find any mentions about this case in Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Please, help me to clarify the case when "bare folder name is passed as the bind folder".
**Where `my_folder` is located on the host?**

*It is enough to give an answer for Windows 10, but it would be great to have answers for general cases in all OS (Win, Linux, Mac)*

Comment: It's located in Docker-internal storage that's not meant to be directly accessed; use a bind mount instead if you do need to directly access the content.  On non-Linux hosts it's further inside a hidden Linux VM with its own isolated filesystem layer.

Comment: @DavidMaze is there any way to remove or clean it up? I accidentally had run that command and suppose that a huge bunch of files could have been created in that folder. So I want to fix that somehow and free the disk space up.

Comment: `docker volume rm my_folder` will delete it.  (You've created a [named volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).)